# How should ajax request html files be formatted?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, xhtml

Im using jquery UI's tabs with ajax.
I was wondering if the files that the ajax calls are gonna retrieve are supposed to be formatted starting with `<html>` or just the minimal html possible cause its gonna be injected into an already formatted valid xhtml file.... I hope Im making myself clear.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to inject what you receive from the server directly into the DOM, you'll want an HTML snippet. Something like

```
<div>This is something <strong>injected</strong></div>
```

is preferred over

```
<html><body><div>This is something <strong>injected</strong></div></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal html.  All the examples on the jquery UI tabs page use HTML shards.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to spit out the HTML exactly as you would want it dropped in to place (i.e. enclosing tags are not necessary).